# Junit test case for if condition inside for-loop

Tags: java, junit

My test cases is getting failed due to `NullPointerException`. Also, am unsure how to handle or debug this null error in junit.

Following is the test cases code :

```
List<String> groupName = new ArrayList<String>();
when(claimGroupingHistoryRepository.getGroupingKeyName(1l)).thenReturn(groupName);
service.updateClaimGroupingKeyForDealer(dealer.getDealerId(), groupingKeyResource, userId);
```

Due to the following piece of code am gettign the `null pointer` error in my test cases. If the comment the `if block`  inside the `for-loop`am not getting the error.  Not sure how to test the if condition here.

```
for(GroupingKeys groupingKey : groupingKeyResource.getGroupingKeys()){          
          if(groupingKey.getValue() != 0) {  // no sure how to check this condition using junit
              List<String> name = claimGroupingHistoryRepository.getGroupingKeyName(groupingKey.getId());
              for(String nameList:name) {
                  if(!groupingName.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                      groupingName = groupingName.concat(", ").concat(nameList);
                  } else {
                      groupingName = nameList;
                  }

              }
          } 
      }
```

Following is the test case error that am getting :

```
ClaimServiceImplTest.shouldUpdateClaimGroupingKeyForDealerUpdate:6057 » NullPointer
```

Please find my complete test file

**Updated: 1***

```
public void shouldUpdateClaimGroupingKeyForDealerUpdate() throws Exception {    
         Dealer dealer = make(a(DealerMaker.Dealer));
         ClaimGroupingHistory claimGroupingHistory = make(a(ClaimGroupingHistoryMaker.ClaimGroupingHistory));

         String userId = "/user/0001";
         Status draft = make(a(Draft));
         User user = make(a(UserMaker.User, with(UserMaker.id, userId),with(UserMaker.email, "user@example.com"))).toUser();
            ArrayList<ClaimGroupingKeyMapping> mapping = new ArrayList<ClaimGroupingKeyMapping>();
            ClaimGroupingKeyMapping e = new ClaimGroupingKeyMapping();
            GroupingKeys groupingKeys= new GroupingKeys();
            groupingKeys.setValue(1l);
            groupingKeys.setCode("code");
            e.setValue(1l);
            e.setGroupingKeys(groupingKeys);
            mapping.add(e); 
        ArrayList<GroupingKeys> grpKey = new ArrayList<GroupingKeys>();
        grpKey.add(new GroupingKeys());
        GroupingKeyResource groupingKeyResource = new GroupingKeyResource();
        groupingKeyResource.setGroupingKeys(grpKey);

        ArrayList<ClaimGroupingHistory> historyLog=new ArrayList<ClaimGroupingHistory>();
        List<String> groupName=new ArrayList<String>();

        when(claimGroupingHistoryRepository.getClaimGroupingHistory(dealer.getDealerId())).thenReturn(historyLog);
        when(claimGroupingHistoryRepository.getGroupingKeyName(groupingKeys.getId())).thenReturn(groupName);

        service.updateClaimGroupingKeyForDealer(dealer.getDealerId(), groupingKeyResource, userId);

    }
```

Comment: Your previous post with this exact question was closed because it's a duplicate, so you start it again?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Junit testcases getting fail due to NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324641/junit-testcases-getting-fail-due-to-npe)

Comment: @Stultuske - i do understand NPE. But here the case is writting test case code for the if condition inside for-loop. Do you have any idea for this case.?

Comment: you don't even show the entire unit to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to be sure of this, unless we see the definition of `GroupingKeys`, but the reason you are getting NPE is because the field `value` is not a primitive.

To avoid NPE, you can initialize `GroupingKeys`, specifically `value` to some number.

Comment: Please find my updated lines `GroupingKeys groupingKeys= new GroupingKeys();
      groupingKeys.setValue(1l);`. But still am getting the same issue.

Comment: You should set value before you perform this: `grpKey.add(new GroupingKeys());`. Otherwise, it has no meaning

Comment: I have updated my code as per ur suggestion. Still am getting the same issue. Please find my updated code.